# How to build two Wicket applications

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket, web.xml

It is about the helloworld example on the following link:

```
http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/helloworld.html
```

The helloworld works fine and I can call the application with the url: `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/`. now I would like to expand the example for second application `hellowolrd2` sothat when I call `http://localhost:8080/helloworld2/` with the browser, a second page helloworld2 comes (similar to helloworld). Assumed I have the files `HelloWorld2.java` and `HelloWorld2.html`.What shall I change in the file web.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to modify anything in `web.xml`. The only relevant setting defined there is the `<filter-mapping>` element

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

, which maps all requests (`/*`) made to the application (its context root) to the Wicket Filter (think of it as a servlet), which will handle all Wicket requests and direct them to the appropriate method (component constructor, event handler method, etc.).

In the example, you see the `HelloWorld` page when requesting `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/` because `HelloWorld` is the home page defined in the `WebApplication`. `helloworld` is the context root for the webapp, so Wicket automatically takes you to the page defined in [`WebApplication#getHomePage()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#getHomePage%28%29):

```
@Override
public Class getHomePage() {
    return HelloWorld.class;
}
```

Notice that `helloworld` here is the application's context root. So unless you want to define some logic in `getHomePage()` to return a class or another depending on some criteria (don't really think this is what you're after), it will effectively serve `HelloWorld`.

Now, addressing your question, with Wicket you can mount (bookmarkable) pages to URL's using [`WebApplication#mountPage()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#getHomePage%28%29):

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends WebApplication {
    @Override
    protected void init() {
        mountPage("/helloworld", HelloWorld.class);
        mountPage("/helloworld2", HelloWorld2.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getHomePage() {
        return HelloWorld.class;
    }
}
```

This would make `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/` serve `HelloWorld` class, being the home page. But would also serve it requesting `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/helloworld`. Requesting `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/helloworld2` would effectively serve `HelloWorld2`.

Or, if you really wanted `http://localhost:8080/helloworld2/` to serve `HelloWorld2`, you should deploy another webapp, of course with its own `web.xml`, and with context-root `helloworld2`.

Comment: this works fine, when I put mountPage() in the method init(). I dont know why it does not work, if moutPage() in the Constructor. Thanks for help

Comment: Yeah, indeed, `mountPage` should be on `init()`, not on the constructor. I've modified the answer. As a side note to the answer, check out this [Wicket in Action entry on page mounting](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-pages/), you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have two applications, actually you have two pages.
The first (helloworld) was mapped by to respond as home page, it was defined in HelloWorldApplication:

```
@Override
public Class getHomePage() {
    return HelloWorld.class;
}
```

If you want localhost:8080/helloworld2/ just create a mapping in the init() method in HelloWorldApplication

```
@Override
public void init() {
super.init();
this.mountPage("/helloworld2", Helloworld2.class);
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that actually `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/helloworld2` will serve this page, not `http://localhost:8080/helloworld2`.

Comment: @XaviLópez Unless the app is mounted into the root context. (It's somewhat confusing to discuss this conceptually without disambiguating the name of the app, and the names of the pages / where they're mounted, of which one can be the "index" for the app.)